# Add pointer and const to std::tuple<Types...>

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, partial-specialization

I'm trying to achieve the following using the magic of `C++11` templates:

Suppose I have a type like this:

```
using my_types = std::tuple<char, int, float>;
```

Having this, I'd like to get a tuple of *pointers* to both `const` and not values, i.e.:

```
std::tuple<char *, int *, float *, const char *, const int *, const float *>;
```

My solution for now:

```
template<typename T>
struct include_const {};

template<typename... Types>
struct include_const<std::tuple<Types...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<Types..., typename std::add_const<Types>::type...>;
};
```

This gives `std::tuple<types, const types>`. To get pointers, I can use:

```
template<typename T>
struct add_ptr {};

template<typename... Types>
struct add_ptr<std::tuple<Types...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<typename std::add_pointer<Types>::type...>;
};
```

This works, but I would like this to get a little more general: I want to have a `template<trait, Types...> add_ptr` that gives me pointers to both `Types...` and `trait<Types>::type...`, so the usage could be the following:

`add_ptr<std::add_const, my_types>` is the tuple i mentioned before
`add_ptr<std::add_volatile, my_types>` gives `std::tuple<char *, volatile char *, ...>`

I would appreciate some hints on how this can be achieved. I'm not yet a template magician and would appreciate some help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a template template-parameter

```
template<template<typename> class Trait, typename U>
struct add_ptr {};

template<template<typename> class Trait, typename... Types>
struct add_ptr<Trait, std::tuple<Types...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<
                    typename std::add_pointer<Types>::type...,
                    typename std::add_pointer<
                        typename Trait<Types>::type
                    >::type...
                >;
};
```

Then

```
add_ptr<std::add_const, my_types>::type
```

will be

```
std::tuple<char *, int *, float *, char const *, int const *, float const *>
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/048832b4e15cdb99)